# Get custom taxonomy value of post and output posts in same taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop

I'm trying to show related videos on my single post template. I've set up a custom taxonomy called 'sub-category' in Posts. I want to get the sub-category of the current post and loop through any posts with the same sub-category, outputting them to the page. 
Any ideas on the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

try with this function

```
function get_posts_in_taxonomy($post_type, $taxonomy, $term_id, $include_children=false, $limit)
{
$args = [
    'post_type'      => $post_type,
    'posts_per_page' => $limit,
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy'         => $taxonomy,
            'terms'            => $term_id,
            'include_children' => $include_children
        ],
    ],
    // Rest of your arguments
];

$posts = new WP_Query( $args );

if($posts->have_posts()) {
    while($posts->have_posts()) {
        $posts->the_post();

        //code todo here

    }
}
} //end func
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function get_the_terms( $post, $taxonomy ) {
if ( ! $post = get_post( $post ) ) {
    return false;
}

$terms = get_object_term_cache( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
if ( false === $terms ) {
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
        $term_ids = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'term_id' );
        wp_cache_add( $post->ID, $term_ids, $taxonomy . '_relationships' );
    }
}

/**
 * Filters the list of terms attached to the given post.
 *
 * @since 3.1.0
 *
 * @param WP_Term[]|WP_Error $terms    Array of attached terms, or WP_Error on failure.
 * @param int                $post_id  Post ID.
 * @param string             $taxonomy Name of the taxonomy.
 */
$terms = apply_filters( 'get_the_terms', $terms, $post->ID, $taxonomy );

if ( empty( $terms ) ) {
    return false;
}

return $terms;}
```

Comment: This is just the source code of `get_the_terms()`. What does that have to do with anything?

Answer (score -1):

I think I confused myself on this actually, here's how I did it:

```
$_terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'sub-category', array("fields" => "all"));
        foreach ($_terms as $term) :
            $term_slug = $term->slug;
            $_posts = new WP_Query( array(
                        'post_type'         => 'post',
                        'posts_per_page'    => 4,
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'sub-category',
                                'field'    => 'slug',
                                'terms'    => $term_slug,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ));
            if( $_posts->have_posts() ) :
                while ( $_posts->have_posts() ) : $_posts->the_post();
                    //Output
                endwhile;
            endif;
            wp_reset_postdata();
            endforeach;
```